# Place overbrace/underbrace outside of a boxed-environment

Tags: equations, labels

Is there a simple way (without complex tikz or that stuff) to place an underbrace/overbrace outside of "boxed"-math environment? Would be great when the braces would have same height position outside of boxed.

```
 \documentclass[15pt,a4paper,headinclude, totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\[ \underset{(22)}{\Leftrightarrow} \boxed{ \overbrace{\frac{ \dfrac{c}{\lambda^2} \cdot \left[ \frac{(\lambda-1-\tau)^2}{1+\tau} + (\lambda-1)^2 \right] }{(\rho + 2 \cdot I - n)}}^{marg. R\&D revenue} = \overbrace{\chi \cdot B(w_L,w_H)}^{marg. R\&D costs} } \tag{32} \]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

This yields:

[image]

Is there a short and fancy way to make this look nice?

Thanks

Comment: Use `\text{marg. R\&D revenue}` and `\text{marg. R\&D costs}`. And for the underbrace/overbrace simply use the command again.

Comment: @azetina I skipped the \text{} command for simplification. My main problem is still the positioning of the braces outside of the box. What do you mean by 'use the command again'? regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no easy way, but in this case, I set the two items to be braced into boxes, and use the width of those boxes to stack the braces outside of the `\boxed` element.

```
\documentclass[15pt,a4paper,headinclude, totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newsavebox\itemA
\savebox\itemA{$\displaystyle\frac{ \dfrac{c}{\lambda^2} \cdot \left[ 
  \frac{(\lambda-1-\tau)^2}{1+\tau} + (\lambda-1)^2 \right] }{(\rho + 2 \cdot I - n)}$}

\newsavebox\itemB
\savebox\itemB{$\chi \cdot B(w_L,w_H)$}

\[ \underset{(22)}{\Leftrightarrow} 
\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackon{%
  \boxed{ \usebox{\itemA} = \usebox{\itemB} }
}{%
  \overbrace{\kern\wd\itemA}^{\text{marg. R\&D revenue}} \phantom{{}={}}
  \overbrace{\kern\wd\itemB}^{\text{marg. R\&D costs}}
}%
 \tag{32} \]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I wanted the output to look like. Thank you. Pity that there's obviously no straightforward/easier way.

Comment: PS: How do you add the output-picture here? I always compile, save picture to png, and upload it on external image-hoster. Is there an easier way on tex-stackexchange to display output?

Comment: @Mac I do a screen capture and save the result in a jpg.  Then, when I click on the include image button of the edit box, I have a choice of either retrieving the image from the web **or** directly from my computer, by clicking the "Browse" button on the pop-up window.  That way, I can avoid the image-hosting middle-man.